# BigQuery full join two tables without a column to join on

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables:

`t1`

```
col1    col2 
a       a
a       c
b       a
b       d
c       a
c       d
```

`t2`

```
team   game
mazs      1
mazs      2
doos      1
bahs      3
...
```

`t2` is a very long table with many teams and games, whereas `t1` is shown in its entirety - a table with 6 rows, featuring combinations of the letters a,b,c,d. Note that `t1` is not a fully exhaustive list of a,b,c,d pairings, only the pairings in the 6 rows that appear.

I'd like to create a table that looks like this:

`output`

```
team  game  col1  col2
mazs     1     a     a
mazs     1     a     c
mazs     1     b     a
mazs     1     b     d
mazs     1     c     a
mazs     1     c     d
mazs     2     a     a
mazs     2     a     c
mazs     2     b     a
mazs     2     b     d
mazs     2     c     a
mazs     2     c     d
```

What's going on here is that for each row in `t2`, there are 6 rows in `output`, one row for each of the `col1, col2` pairings from `t1`.

`t1` and `t2` are created on my end from the following queries:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM sometable GROUP BY col1, col2
SELECT DISTINCT team, game FROM anothertable
```

The first query creates `t1` and the second query creates `t2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called `CROSS JOIN`, see below example:

```sql
With t1 as (
select 'a' col1, 'a' col2 union all
select 'a' col1, 'c' col2 union all
select 'b' col1, 'a' col2 union all
select 'b' col1, 'd' col2 union all
select 'c' col1, 'a' col2 union all
select 'c' col1, 'd' col2),
t2 as (
select 'mazs' team, 1 game union all
select 'mazs' team, 2 game union all
select 'doos' team, 1 game union all
select 'bahs' team, 3 game
) 

SELECT * FROM t2 cross join t1;
```

Output:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| team | game | col1 | col2 |
+------+------+------+------+
| mazs |    1 | a    | a    |
| mazs |    1 | a    | c    |
| mazs |    1 | b    | a    |
| mazs |    1 | b    | d    |
| mazs |    1 | c    | a    |
| mazs |    1 | c    | d    |
| mazs |    2 | a    | a    |
| mazs |    2 | a    | c    |
| mazs |    2 | b    | a    |
| mazs |    2 | b    | d    |
| mazs |    2 | c    | a    |
| mazs |    2 | c    | d    |
| doos |    1 | a    | a    |
| doos |    1 | a    | c    |
| doos |    1 | b    | a    |
| doos |    1 | b    | d    |
| doos |    1 | c    | a    |
| doos |    1 | c    | d    |
| bahs |    3 | a    | a    |
| bahs |    3 | a    | c    |
| bahs |    3 | b    | a    |
| bahs |    3 | b    | d    |
| bahs |    3 | c    | a    |
| bahs |    3 | c    | d    |
+------+------+------+------+
```